# How can I make an array a parameter of a function in C++?

Tags: c++, encryption, hash

I have a function in a program I am writing for my school science fair, and what it needs to do is take in an array as a parameter, encrypt the values of the array, and store the encrypted values in a string. How can I do this?

Comment: How do you obtain the array? in a `vector`, `array`, just c style array, or something else?

Comment: What part is causing you problems? You can pass the name of an array as an argument to a function that takes a pointer-to-type as a parameter; ie, you can pass `int a[10]` to `foo(int *p)` . Of course, `foo()` won't know the size of `a` -- you have to pass that as a second argument.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough. What is the correct way to write:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void YourFunction(const int myarray[]);
```

Otherwise if you want accept **any** type

```
void YourFunction(const void* myGenericArray);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That's not enough - you don't know the size of the array. Also, the question is tagged C++, so generics really should be done with templates rather than `void*`.

Comment: you cannot use `const`: the OP needs to change the values in the array.

Comment: @Vlad, that isn't my reading of the requirement. The array is an input parameter. A string is the output parameter.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: With an imprecise question, I can obviusly write this only. However if you are using functions in C++, there isn't a problem in using void*, I mean, you are still using C++ as a C program when you use it through functions instead working with it as an object oriented program.

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to do this. Here are few examples:

- C-style

  ```
  void f(T *array, size_t size);
  ```

  In this style, the array decay to the pointer to the first argument which gets passed to the function as first argument. Since this conversion loses the size of the array, you've to pass the size as well, which I do as second argument to the function. Use this as:

  ```
  T  array[N]; //N is some compile-time constant.
  f(array, N);
  ```
- C++-style

  ```
  template<typename T, size_t size>
  void f(T (&array)[size]);

  void f(std::vector<T> & array);
  ```

  In this style, you can pass the array by reference, which retains the size of the array, or you can use `std::vector<T>` instead. Use this as:

  ```
  T array[N];
  f(array); //calls the first version (the template version)

  std::vector<T> v;
  //fill v
  f(v); //calls the vector version
  ```

  Added by @Mike: or you can use this, which is even better:

  ```
  template<typename FwdIterator>
  void f(FwdIterator begin, FwdIterator end)
  {
     for( ; begin != end ; ++begin)
     {
          //your code
     }
  }
  ```

  This is better and more generic, because with it, you can use standard containers (such as `std::vector`, `std::list`, etc) as well as normal arrays. For example,

  ```
  T array[N];
  std::vector<T> v;
  //fill v

  f(array, array+N);      //okay
  f(v.begin(), v.end());  //also okay.
  ```

  Cool, isn't it?

Comment: And for extra genericness, `template <typename It> void f(It start, It end);`

Comment: @Mike: this way the code would compile for the call like `f(&var1, &var2)` for any variables `var1`/`var2` of the same type -- which kind of breaks compile-time safety.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Thanks for that.  Added it to my post.

Comment: @Vlad: That is the problem with all sort of standard containers, but the point is that you have to read the documentation, before using the function. If you don't read the doc, then you can write such code, no matter how you write functions.

Comment: @Nawaz: well, compile-time safety is protecting from silly mistakes/typos. Imagine that you are using the function as `f(&a[0], &a[5])` (perfectly legitimate), and I come and change all the occurrences of `a` to `b`, except only one by mistake. The compiler won't catch this. If we want to leave our users with documentation alone, without the helpful compiler support, we could use the most generic `void*` as well. (Note aside: I think this is the problem of C++ templates: they are too powerful and too close to macros.)

Comment: @Vlad: I know that already, and even your answer doesn't answer it in any better way.

Comment: @Nawaz: I don't say in any way that my answer covers this topic. I just want to express that by the virtue of C++ templates the code will compile for `It` being "anything that supports `++`, `!=` and unary `*`", which is really much broader that the original code's intent. (And there's no [easy?] way in C++ to express "exactly the C-style array or standard container".)

Comment: @Vlad: I don't see any point or advantage in dragging this discussion further, as no language is idiot-proof. As I said, you have to take *some* responsibilities yourself, before using the function, that is, learn how to call the function properly!

Comment: @Nawaz: Well, just having signature like `void f(std::vector<T>&)` is more error-proof then abusing the template power: with such a signature one cannot make a mistake like that which I mentioned. C++ _can_ be more "idiot-proof" or "silly-mistake-friendly", that's my point.

Comment: @Vlad: With power comes responsibility. the vector version is not as powerful and generic as the iterator version. Iterators are powerful, that is why the `<algorithm>` contains so many of them!

Answer (score 0):

```
void encrypt(Array& array, /*other parameters*/)
```

would do, whatever array type you use.

If your array is a C-style pointer, you can also just pass it:

```
void encrypt(int* array, /*other parameters*/)
```